# Removing A Variant via the API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, shopify

When I try to remove a variant for a product through the API, I get a 404 error the following:

```
def destroy_shopify_variant(variant_id)
    ShopifyAPI::Variant.delete({ :id => variant_id })
end
```

I know that the variant_id is valid. I'm just not sure if I'm passing all the correct params or not. I could not find any documentation on api docs.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd try reporting an issue on that library here: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ShopifyAPI::Variant.delete(variant_id) will work as long as it's not the only variant associated with that product, otherwise you'll get a HTTP 423 response.